# FindFirstFileEx doesn't operate case sensitive

Tags: c#, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Since I'm using a macro which seems to work if the given path is case unequal to the local path on the drive I first need to validate wether the path is case-wise existing or not. Unfortunately (in my case) `Directory.Exists()` is not case sensitive.

So I tried [FindFirstFileEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/findfirstfileex.html) with `dwAdditionalAttributes` set to `1` which stands for [FIND_FIRST_EX_CASE_SENSITIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/aa364419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However it seems not work for me. My local path is `C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3`. The path I compare is `C:\dir1\Dir2\Dir3`. Unfortunately I always get `Dir3` as a result. I would have expected an empty result if the cases don't match.

What is my fault?

```
string dir = @"C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3" + '\0';
int FIND_FIRST_EX_CASE_SENSITIVE = 1;
WIN32_FIND_DATA fi;

IntPtr h = FindFirstFileEx( dir,
                            FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS.FindExInfoStandard,
                            out fi,
                            FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS.FindExSearchNameMatch,
                            IntPtr.Zero,
                            FIND_FIRST_EX_CASE_SENSITIVE);
```

Comment: You actual path is the same as the path you're passing as a parameter. Is it a typo in the question?

Comment: Seems to me that you should resolve the original issue in another way instead of relying on the casing of file system objects in a case-insensitive environment. What does not work with that macro?

Comment: @ken2k thanks, my fault. @ 0xA3 the macro stops expanding the folders in a folder browser dialog until it comes to the not matching cases. I can't change the macro itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality depends on value of registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\obcaseinsensitive` being set set to 0, which is not the default.

In other words, it depends on underlying file system settings, not the API itself.

more details here: http://www.siao2.com/2010/12/08/10101148.aspx

Answer (score 2):

By default, file searches in Windows are always case insensitive, regardless of the use of `FIND_FIRST_EX_CASE_SENSITIVE`.

To change this, you have to change a value in the registry (as far as I know).

See here for the gory details:

http://www.nicklowe.org/2012/02/understanding-case-sensitivity-in-windows-obcaseinsensitive-file_case_sensitive_search/

In your case, I expect

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Kernel, REG DWORD obcaseinsensitive` is set to 1

Comment: If I set it 0. Do I need to reboot? Because FindFirstFileEx still found something...

Comment: Oh my goodness... Is there any other way I can validate case sensitive? I can reboot the system because other will use it, too.

Comment: it's not just that others might use it - it might also break other things. Here's from the article I linked: `The practical effect of this is changing the registry key "lights up" latent bugs in NT applications and drivers that are not expecting case sensitive behavior.`